# Setup Postfix as a relay / filter

Tags: postfix, smtp

I need to have Postfix set up to work with Lamson. Despite my research on the web, i haven't figured out how to configure postfix.

I'll have a server (A) that will forward all its email to a second server (B) (postfix/Lamson). After some processing, server B will forward the email to different mailboxes on a third server (C).

I can imagine postfix (server B) receiving all its email from server A in a single maildir, lamson (server B) processing the email from this maildir (using the method described here: http://lamsonproject.org/docs/deferred_processing_to_queues.html) and "relaying" it to   postfix (server B) for it to do the actual sending to the different mailboxes on server C.

How can I configure postfix to do this? (one maildir for email server A, one for email from lamson...?) I am even on the right track?

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

As the [**Lamson FAQ**](http://lamsonproject.org/docs/faq.html) says, it is a fully compliant SMTP server.

Hence, you would connect Server A directly to Lamson on Server B, without any need for postfix.

Comment: I understood that, but it's stated that lamson is not that performant to receive and deliver lots of email (in the [About page](http://lamsonproject.org/about.html) and [here](http://librelist.com/browser//lamson/2011/2/27/lamson-challenged-noob-question/#e280d450f7baf673a644367c8d38d736) on Librelist). Hence the idea to use postfix.

Comment: The lamson site died, here is the FAQ: https://github.com/zedshaw/lamson/blob/master/doc/lamsonproject.org/input/docs/faq.txt